# Transaction Scope locks database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ado.net, transactionscope

I have use transaction scope when inserting data into two table in a single call. But transaction scope held the database or lock the database for a particular scope that time another user not able to perform any operation on the database.So please tell me the alternative solution for avoiding such situation.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    CamphorTray_OrderDetails ct = new CamphorTray_OrderDetails();

    ct.CamphorTray_ID = ctv.CamphorTray_ID;
    ct.Temple_ID = ctv.Temple_ID;
    ct.For_Date = ctv.For_Date;
    ct.Deity = ctv.Deity;
    ct.Note_Cash = ctv.Note_Cash;
    ct.Coin = ctv.Coin;
    ct.Total_amount = ctv.Total_amount;
    ct.Created_By = ctv.Created_By;
    ct.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
    ct.Modified_By = ctv.Created_By;
    ct.Modified_Date = DateTime.Now;

    CTOD.Insert(ct);

    InsertAudit_CamphorTray_OrderDetails(ct, "Insert");
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: What isolation level are you using by default? This might be a reason....

Answer (score 2):

The ability of other users to access the data of your transaction and your ability to access theirs and the databases' attempts to make sure this works (by locking tables and/or rows) can be controlled by the `TransactionOptions`.

For example this would be the most unsafe, but probably most "allowing" way:

```
var options = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted };

using (var tranScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
 {
```

But please consider before you simply use this: an Isolation level is a *good thing*. It helps keeping your data in a stable state. Ignoring it will lead to all kinds of strange errors. Your database has tremendous power to help you, don't just turn it off because it seems hard to do it correctly.